# How do you choose proper threshold for autoscale on PaaS?

Tags: machine-learning, cloud, scale, autoscaling, paas

Many cloud provider have feature to configure the threshold range to auto scale user application (ex. scale-out when CPU > 70-80% ) so, What're your solution to finding the proper threshold for auto scale and If I want to use machine learning to find proper threshold which one algorithm is good for this work ?
best regard,